# Artikel geografischer Namen

Tags: article

Vor wenigen Minuten hörte ich im Fernsehen (ORF) diesen Satz (aus dem Gedächtnis):

> Der Vorarlberg sticht aus den Wahlergebnissen heraus.

Der Arlberg ist ein Berg in den Alpen, der die Bundesländer Vorarlberg und Tirol voneinander trennt. Aus Sicht der Vorarlberger liegt ihr Bundesland vor dem Arlberg, daher der Name Vor-Arlberg. Weil dieses Land aber eigentlich »Vor-dem-Arlberg« heißt, frage ich mich, ob es gerechtfertigt ist, diesem Land einen männlichen Artikel zuzuordnen.

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl werden die meisten Länder immer ohne Artikel benutzt. Ausnahmen gibt es nur dann, wenn der Name auf »-land«, »-mark«, »-reich« oder Ähnliches endet (das Burgenland, die Steiermark und das Niederösterreich, um bei österreichischen Bundesländern zu bleiben). Aber Ländern wie Tirol und Kärnten würde ich gar kein grammatikalisches Geschlecht zuordnen.

Unklar ist mir aber, wie mit Namen wie »Salzburg« oder »Vorarlberg« umzugehen ist. »Die Salzburg« ist für mich kein Land, sondern eine bestimmte Burg (wobei die Burg die dem Bundesland den Namen gibt in Wahrheit nicht »Salzburg«, sondern »Hohensalzburg« heißt). Und »der Vorarlberg« klingt für mich wie der Name eines Berges (den es aber in Wirklichkeit nicht gibt), nicht wie der Name eines Landes.

Comment: Ich würde es durch "das Land Vorarlberg" eindeutig machen.

Comment: Das es auf Wahlergebnisse bezieht wurde der männliche Artikel vielleicht für den `Wahlbezirk` oder `Wahlkreis` mit dem selben Namen genommen.

Comment: Der Hauptgrund, weshalb du den meisten Ländern "keinen" Artikel zuordnest, ist vermutlich, weil sie sächlich ("das") sind. Dabei entfällt der direkten Nennung - z.B "in Deutschland". Bei allen anderen Artikeln wird er allerdings benutzt - zB "in den Niederlanden", "in der Schweiz", "im Sudan". Das ganze wird allerdings nicht unbedingt einfacher dadurch, dass diverse Nachrichtensprecher darauf bestehen, dass es "in Iran" und "in Irak" heisst.

Comment: Das liegt daran, dass das Sächliche bei Ländernamen immer mehr um sich greift. Im Englischen gibt es eine ähnliche Entwicklung, wo das "the" immer öfter auch bei Ländern weggelassen wird, wo es früher zwingend war (The Argentine, the Congo, the Yemen, the Lebanon, the Sudan, the Ukraine ...)

Answer (score 7):

"Der Vorarlberg" kann ich mir ehrlich gesagt nicht vorstellen; das hielte ich für falsch.

> Nach meinem Sprachgefühl werden die meisten Länder immer ohne Artikel benutzt. Ausnahmen gibt es nur dann, wenn der Name auf "-land", "-mark", "-reich" oder ähnliches endet (das Burgenland, die Steiermark, das Niederösterreich um bei österreichischen Bundesländern zu bleiben).

Alle Bundesländer haben Artikel (das Wien, das Nieder-/Oberösterreich, das Salzburg, das Vorarlberg, usw.), man verwendet sie nur idR nicht: In Kärnten, in Wien, in Oberösterreich, in Salzburg, in Tirol ... die beiden einzigen Ausnahmen sind das Burgenland (*im* Burgenland), und die Steiermark (*in der* Steiermark). Den bestimmten Artikel verwendet man sonst nur, wenn man einen bestimmten Aspekt hervorhebt, zb:

> Das Wien der Zwischenkriesgszeit ... das moderne Salzburg ...

Insofern halte ich *der* Vorarlberg für falsch; natürlich muss es *das* Vorarlberg heißen.

Comment: Und die Pfalz? Okay, das kann man noch als komplett aus einem Bestandteil zusammengesetzt sehen. Aber das Allgäu? Es gibt konkurrierende Etymologien; es ist keineswegs ausgemacht, dass *-gäu* als Nebenform von *Gau* entstanden ist.

Comment: Meine Ausführungen gelten, so wie die Frage, nur für Österreich. Aber weder "Pfalz" noch "Allgäu" sind (deutsche) Bundesländer, so dass sich mir Dein Kommentar hier insgesamt nicht restlos erschließt.

Comment: Zumindest die Kurpfalz war bis 1777 ein eigenständiges Herzogtum/Kurfürstentum, ab dann bis 1946 als Rheinpfalz oder Kurpfalz Regierungsbezirk Bayerns (vor 1862 *Kreis* genannt). Das Allgäu hat tatsächlich keine klaren Grenzen. Andererseits gibt es keinen Grund, warum sich die deutsche Sprache nur für österreichische Bundesländer anders verhalten sollte als für andere Flächengebietsbezeichnungen. Ich lese Huberts Frage im Übrigen so, dass er die österreichischen Bundesländer lediglich als Beispiel/Aufhänger benutzt.

Answer (score 3):

Es gibt keine Regel, nach der sich die Artikel von Namen ergeben.
Meistens bezieht sich der Artikel auf das letzte Wort, aus dem der Name gebildet wird.

Beispiel:

- Die Bergstraße (eine Region in Südhessen)
  „Die“ bezieht sich hier auf „Straße“.
- Die Mecklenburger Seenplatte
  „Die Platte“
- Der Vogelsberg
  „Der Berg“
- Das Ruhrgebiet
  „Das Gebiet“

Bei Regionen mag das in den allermeisten Fällen zutreffen, bei anderen Namen nicht zwangsläufig.
Ein gutes Beispiel ist der Markenname „Nutella“.
Die Leute streiten sich bis heute, ob es „das“ Nutella (Argument: das Nussnougatmus) oder „die“ Nutella (italienisch-weibliche Form) heißt.

Comment: Die Argumentation ist Mus. Für fast jeden Begriff findet sich eine übergeordnete Kategorie, bei der das Geschlecht ein anderes als beim betrachteten Begriff ist. Die Burg, das Bauwerk, der Artefakt, das Materielle ... Nussnougatmus ist wg. des Mus sächlich, wie das Apfel-, Erdbeer und das Birnenmus. Trotzdem ist es die Erdbeere und der Apfel. Regional heißt es übrigens 'der Mus'. ;) P.S.: Das Nürnberg. Das Würzburg.

Answer (score 1):

Das Wort Vorarlberg lässt sich auf zwei Arten aufteilen:

`(Vor-arl)-berg` als der Berg vor dem Arl oder `Vor-(arl-berg)` als das Etwas vor dem Arlberg. Im ersten Fall ist es ein zusammengesetzter Genitiv und der männliche Artikel kommt von `Berg` (der Berg).

Es liegt aber der zweite Fall vor: Es soll das Land **vor** dem Arlberg bezeichnet werden. Meine Formulierung nimmt das Fazit schon vorweg: Hier sollte der Artikel dann von `Land` kommen, also Neutrum.

Ich gebe dir recht, @Hubert, ich finde auch, dass der Artikel in diesem Fall Neutrum sein sollte.

Comment: Das Wort *Land* kommt in *Vorarlberg* nicht vor und kann daher auch keinen Artikel stiften.

Comment: Es heißt trotzdem *das* Voralrberg. Beispiele:  Das offizielle Vorarlberg begeht den Festtag mit Hochämtern ... Das Vorarlberg der Klerikalen ist ein Land kultureller Rückwärtsgewandtheit ...  und während noch heute das Vorarlberg der überbliebene Urbesitz des Hauses ist, liegt der Kern der östreichischen Herrschaft schon lange ... QED.

Comment: @marstato Ich habe nicht behauptet, dass »Vorarlberg« neutrum sein sollte. Ich habe gesagt, dass ich die Richtigkeit von »der Vorarlberg« anzweifle und stattdessen gar keinen Artikel benutzen würde.

Comment: Das Land, die Gegend, der Landstrich - gäbe es eine derartige Regel hätte man die freie Wahl. Da man diese nicht hat muss diese erfundene Regel falsch sein.

Comment: Die Argumentation ist schief, denn der Artikel sollte dann nicht von _Land_ (das gar nicht auftaucht), sondern von _Vor_ kommen – und tatsächlich wäre es dann Neutrum (wie in _das Vor-und-Zurück_). In echten Komposita ist im Deutschen aber **immer** das Rechtselement genusbestimmend und dann wäre die Zerlegungsreihenfolge egal, weil _+berg_ immer entscheidend wäre. Man könnte vielleicht argumentieren, es sei ein verkürzter Name der Langbezeichnung _das Vorarlberger/-ische Land_. Vergleiche auch _die Pfalz_ vs. _(das) Rheinland-Pfalz_ oder _(das) Brandenburg_.

Answer (score 1):

Das Vorhandensein oder Nichtvorhandensein von Artikeln vor Gebietsbezeichnungen wird meistens durch die Gewohnheit bestimmt. Manche Gebiete verlangen Artikel, manche wehren sich dagegen, manche kann man sowohl mit als auch ohne verwenden.

Jedes Gebiet kann man hingegen mithilfe von Artikel und Attribut genauer definieren: schön**es** Österreich, **das** Deutschland der dreißiger Jahre, mein**e** Niederlande. Hierbei bekommen diejenigen Gebiete, die keinen zwingend vorgeschriebenen oder erlaubten Artikel haben, grundsätzlich Neutrum.

Bekannter ist das am Beispiel von Staatsnamen: Es gibt die Niederlande (Plural), Dänemark (verweigert Artikel), den Irak (fast immer gesetzt; maskulin), die Türkei (obligat; feminin), das Kosovo (möglich, neutrum).

Gebietsnamen machen da natürlich keine Ausnahme: das Allgäu, der Bliesgau, der Spreewald, die Hallertau, die Pfalz, Westfalen, das Tessin, das Außerfern, das Burgenland, das Salzburger Land oder Salzburg, Tirol, …

Mir ist jetzt kein richtiger Fallstrick eingefallen, aber es gibt sie mit Sicherheit: Gebiete, deren letzter Bestandteil einen Artikel vermuten lässt, deren Geschlecht aber ein anderes ist. Auf Staatenebene ein halber Fall: Däne*mark* lässt vermuten, dass man es hier mit ein**er** Mark zu tun habe; mit Artikel ist es aber **das** flache Dänemark. (Allerdings wird Dänemark normalerweise artikellos verwendet, was die Analyse erschwert.)

Die einzigen autoritativen Quellen, wie ein (deutschsprachiges) Land auszusprechen ist und welchen Artikel es tragen soll, sind die alteingesessenen Bewohner selbst. Mein Spezl aus Bregenz hat mir vor kurzem bestätigt, dass es *das* Vorarlberg ist, wie ich beim formulieren der Antwort vermutet habe.

---

Übrigens bezeichnet der Arlberg nicht einen Berg im heutigen Sinne – also einen Gipfel –, sondern einen Berg im älteren Sinne – einen Pass. Man hat über den Arlberg (heute würde man *Arlpass* sagen, müsste man ihn neu benennen) gemusst, um von Feldkirch ins restliche Österreich zu kommen. Vor dem Arlberg liegt das Bundesland sowohl aus heilig-römischer wie auch aus Schweizer und aus Burg-Habsburger Sicht (die [Habsburger Burg](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habsburg_%28Burg%29) steht im Aargau in der Schweiz).

Comment: _Gewohnheitsrecht_ ist etwas anderes: Gewohnheit, Sprachgebrauch, Überlieferung, Brauchtum ... was auch immer, aber Gewohnheits*recht* ist, vereinfacht, das Gegenstück zum gesatzten (also in Gesetzesform, schriftlich ergangenen) Recht, und das ist hier wohl nicht gemeint.

In meinem Sprachgebrauch heißt es übrigens **der** Kosovo. Für _Vorarlberg_ ist mit diesen Ausführungen aber trotzdem nichts gewonnen.

Und: nicht immer kann man die Einwohner dazu befragen, vor allem wenn sie nicht dieselbe Sprache sprechen: zB der Kongo, der Tschad, der Niger ...

Comment: Beim artikellosen Namen _Dänemark_ verhält es sich ähnlich wie bei _Deutschland_: beide haben scheinbar ein Rechtselement mit eindeutigem Genus (_die Mark_ und _das Land_), werden aber nicht als echtes Kompositum, sondern als eine Einheit aufgefasst. Die Komposita wären wahrscheinlich _die *Däne**n**mark_ und _das *Deutsch**en**land_.

Comment: @Crissov Man kann das Vorhandensein oder Abwesendsein von Komposita nicht an Fugenlauten erkennen: Vergleiche **die** Finnmark (nicht *Finnenmark*), eine Verwaltungseinheit Norwegens. Ich gebe dir allerdings Recht, dass man Finnmark noch viel eher als Kompositum auffassen täte als Dänemark.